# Generic return type based on inner map?

Tags: java, class, generics, casting

I've got a function that is trying to map field names (strings) to class types, and then is able to convert an input string into the correct type based on the input field name.

```
public class Parser {
  private final Map<String, Class> mapping;
  public Parser(Map<String, Class> inputMapping){
    this.mapping = inputMapping;
  }

  public T parseString(String fieldName, String parseValue){
     Object convertedObject;
     Class<T> classType = mapping.get(fieldName);
     if(classType == String.class) {
       convertedObject = parseValue;
     } else if (classType == Double.class) {
       convertedObject = Double.valueOf(parseValue);
     } else {
       throw new UnimplementedException("Invalid type");
     }
     return classType.cast(convertedObject);
  }
}
```

I'm getting errors with this though that say "Cannot find symbol 'T'" in reference to the T being used in the return type of parseString. Is there anyway to correct this error or reorganize the function to have the same behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do this type-safely. All you can do is to return `Object`.

Comment: `public <T> T parseString`

Comment: @Aominè.... which would not be type safe, because you can call `Integer i = parseString("field", "parse");` as well as `Double d = parseString("field", "parse");`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I didn't pay much attention to the description but for sure solves the compilation error the OP is getting.

Comment: @Aominè don't change compile-time errors into runtime errors. The former are far easier to catch than the latter.

Comment: @AndyTurner Right. ok.

Comment: @Coat what you're trying to do here might be better solved with a type-safe heterogeneous container. These are described in *Effective Java*. Basically, you need the type information to be conveyed in the `fieldName` parameter.

Comment: @AndyTurner your comment above about parseString("field", "parse") returning Integers and Doubles is probably the best illustration of how important type safety is that I've seen!

I'll try and redesign the code so that field name passes the class itself to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do something here which can't be done in the `Parser` class.

Java methods have a fixed return type. It can be generic, but the return type of the value cannot be chosen inside the method. The returned *value* can, clearly, but the return *type* is fixed.

What you're trying to do here is to parse specific fields to specific types. In the sense you are trying to use it, a "field" is actually a `Function<String, SomeType>`. If you know the type of the field you expect, you have to know the name of the field. So, instead of:

```
Integer i = parser.get("int_field", "1");  // Can't do this.
Double d = parser.get("double_field", "1");  // Can't do this.
```

instead, you can do:

```
Function<String, Integer> intFieldParser = Integer::parseInt;
Function<String, Double> doubleFieldParser = Double::parseDouble;

Integer i = intFieldParser.apply("1");
Double d = doubleFieldParser.apply("1");
```

i.e. you retain the type information by keeping the parsers separate. This avoids the need for the `Parser` class entirely.

If you *have to* put the things into a map (for example, you don't know the fields at compile time), the best you can do is to return a common supertype:

```
Number i = parser.parse("int_field", "1");
Number d = parser.parse("double_field", "1");
```

The values can be `Integer` and `Double`; but client code has to work that out; you can't know it at compile time.